# How can I print php variables in text file?

Tags: php, html

I want to print php variable in a text file.

Example  :

```
<?php
$name='x' ;
?>
```

I want to put name value in text file for print it as hard copy .

Comment: So you are trying to save a string to a file? have a look at [file_put_contents](http://www.php.net/file_put_contents).

Answer (score 1):

Following is how to accomplish it.

```
<?php file_put_contents('filename', 'content');
```

[Have a look at this function at PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Answer (score 0):

Since your question does not include anything you have tried on your own (Which is generally recommended). Here is somewhere for you to start - the php [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) function.

You can try something like this:

```
<?php
$file = 'some-file.txt';
$name = "x";
// Write the contents to the file
file_put_contents($file, $name);
?>
```

A few Google searches will surely provide some insight here as well.

Hope it helps!